# TeXstudio: Is there a way to keep my custom macros and shortcuts in a separate file?

Tags: macros, texstudio, keyboard

I've created some macros and corresponding shortcuts; found them in my `texstudio.ini` file (`Macros` and `keysetting` keys), buried deep among lots of predefined stuff. Is there a way to 'modularize' it a bit? Put the macros and the shortcuts in a separate file and then 'include' it?

Comment: menu `options->save profile...`

Comment: No, it is not really working. I tried to share a profile over the Dropbox, unsuccessfully (at least shortcuts got messed).

Comment: FWIW: shared profile looks usable via soft links to an external (on Dropbox, for instance) profile in `~/.config/texstudio`

Answer (score 1):

Macros and keysettings are part of the profile. There is currently no way to handle them separately.